# How to apply Seq map function?

Tags: f#, seq

I been recently playing with F# . I was wondering instead of using a for loop to generate a sequence to element which are multiplied with every other element in the list how can I use a Seq map function or something similar to generate something like below.

So for e.g. I have a list [1..10] I would like to apply a fun which generates a result something like

```
[(1*1); (1*2);(1*3); (1*4); (1*5)......(2*1);(2*2);(2*3).....(3*1);(3*2)...]
```

How can i achieve this ?.

Many thanks for all you help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let list = [1..10]

list |> List.map (fun v1 -> List.map (fun v2 -> (v1*v2)) list) |> List.collect id
```

The List.collect at the end flattens the list of lists.
It works the same with Seq instead of List, if you want a lazy sequence.

Or, using `collect` as the main iterator, as cfern suggested and obsessivley eliminating anonymous functions:

```
let flip f x y = f y x

let list = [1..10]

list |> List.collect ((*) >> ((flip List.map) list))
```

Comment: Thanks @Mau works great, The 'collect' operation is great, came across first time after all the posts on my question. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

A list comprehension would be the easiest way to do this:

```
let allpairs L = 
    [for x in L do
        for y in L -> (x*y)]
```

Or, without using any loops:

```
let pairs2 L = L |> List.collect (fun x -> L |> List.map (fun y -> (x*y)))
```

*Edit in response to comment:*
You could add a self-crossing extension method to a list like this:

```
type Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List<'a> with
    member L.cross f = 
        [for x in L do
            for y in L -> f x y]
```

Example:

```
> [1;2;3].cross (fun x y -> (x,y));;
val it : (int * int) list =
  [(1, 1); (1, 2); (1, 3); (2, 1); (2, 2); (2, 3); (3, 1); (3, 2); (3, 3)]
```

I wouldn't use an extension method in F# myself, is feels a bit C#'ish. But that's mostly because I don't feel that a fluent syntax is needed in F# because I usually chain my functions together with pipe (|>) operators.

My approach would be to extend the List module with a cross function, not the type itself:

```
module List =
    let cross f L1 L2 = 
        [for x in L1 do
            for y in L2 -> f x y]
```

If you do this, you can use the cross method like any other method of List:

```
> List.cross (fun x y -> (x,y)) [1;2;3] [1;2;3];;
val it : (int * int) list =
  [(1, 1); (1, 2); (1, 3); (2, 1); (2, 2); (2, 3); (3, 1); (3, 2); (3, 3)]
> List.cross (*) [1;2;3] [1;2;3];;
val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 2; 4; 6; 3; 6; 9]
```

Comment: Thaks @cfern, I like the list comprehension way. Another thing I was wondering can you actually make the list comprehension you have shown as an extension method like we have in C# . If yes how can I make it an extension method ?. Would love to know. Thanks

Comment: @netmatrix01: I've added an extra explanation extension method to my post. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Great thanks @cfern , your solution is extremely elegant. I can also see you recommendation of not using extension method rather extend the List module with a cross function. Its excellent approach. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Or we can implement a general cross product function:

```
let cross l1 l2 =
  seq { for el1 in l1 do
          for el2 in l2 do
            yield el1, el2 };;
```

and use this function to get the job done:

```
cross [1..10] [1..10] |> Seq.map (fun (a,b) -> a*b) |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: Or you can add a function parameter to cross, so the result would be cross [1..10] [1..10] (*).

The question was asking how to do it without for loops, however.

Comment: Thanks @Yin for your solution. It works great and as i understand the list created would be a lazy list for always a good idea. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

To implement the same thing without `for` loops, you can use the solution using *higher-order functions* posted by Mau, or you can write the same thing explicitly using recursion:

```
let cross xs ys =
  let rec crossAux ol2 l1 l2 =
    match l1, l2 with
    // All elements from the second list were processed
    | x::xs, [] -> crossAux ol2 xs ol2             
    // Report first elements and continue looping after
    // removing first element from the second list
    | x::xs, y::ys -> (x, y)::(crossAux ol2 l1 ys) 
    // First list is empty - we're done
    | [], _ -> []
  crossAux ys xs ys
```

This may be useful if you're learning functional programming and recursion, however, the solution using sequence expressions is far more practically useful.

As a side-note, the first version by Mau can be made a bit nicer, because you can join the call to `List.map` with a call to `List.collect id` like this (you can pass the nested processing lambda directly as a parameter to `collect`). The `cross` function would look like this (Of course, you can modifiy this to take a parameter to apply to the two numbers instead of creating a tuple):

```
let cross xs ys =
  xs |> List.collect (fun v1 -> 
    ys |> List.map (fun v2 -> (v1, v2)))
```

---

Incidentally, there is a [free chapter](http://www.manning.com/petricek/SampleChapter12.pdf) from my book avaialable, which discusses how sequence expressions and `List.collect` functions work. It is worth noting, that `for` in *sequence expressions* directly corresponds to `List.collect`, so you can write the code just by using this higher order function:

```
let cross xs ys =
  xs |> List.collect (fun v1 -> 
    ys |> List.collect (fun v2 -> [(v1, v2)] ))
```

However, see the free chapter for more information :-).

Comment: Thanks @Tomas , Brilliant answer. I especially appreciate your effort with respect to recursion function. I agree with your comment as a beginner to FP it would be helpful for me to learn the recursion techniques. I have actually got your book about 4 -5 months back, just havent managed to go past page 30-35 because of work commitments. But very soon i am going to be reading and experimenting all the examples in your book cover to cover. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i just been trying your recursion technique but unfortunately i get Stackoverflow exception. I had also been trying to debug it but it bombs out as soon it tries to enter match block, As i am new to this technique i am unable to fix the problem. Would be helpful if you can tell what might be the problem. On a similar note was wondering what are the best technique to debug a recursion function as i had always found them tricky. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @netmatrix01: For what inputs do you get the exception? Unfortunately, debugging recursion is really quite tricky - in Visual Studio, you can view the stack trace and navigate through it to see the recursive calls that were made. That's often quite useful.

Comment: Hi @Tomas, So i tried something like this 

open System.Linq

let pal = cross [100..999] [100..999] |> Seq.filter (fun i-> i.ToString().SequenceEqual(i.ToString().Reverse())) |> Seq.max;;